# gnuplot: draw polygon from data

Tags: gnuplot

How can I plot polygons with data coming from a file? For example if I have a file containing coordinates of the edges of a four-point polygon for each data point, how would I proceed?

e.g. a data file containing

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2
```

should draw two quadratic rectangular wit center at position (0.5,0.5) and (2.5,2.5).

Comment: The most reasonable plotting style for this is `boxxyerrorbars`, there is no dedicated style for rectangles or polygons.

Comment: In my example there are recatangles but in my real data I have other figures, but all with 4 points defining an edge. I have found this: http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/polygon/ but I cannot figure out how I could apply this to my situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gnuplot doesn't have a dedicated plotting style for plotting arbitrary quadrangles. For that, you must use a different data file format like

```
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 0
0 0

2 2
2 3
3 3
1 0
0 0
```

which you can then simply plot with `plot 'file.txt' using 1:2 with lines`. The empty line between the two parts tells gnuplot to not connect the rectangles.

If you cannot or don't want to change the data file format, you can change the data on-the-fly with an external tool like

```
plot '< awk ''{print $1,$2,"\n",$3,$4,"\n",$5,$6,"\n",$7,$8,"\n",$1,$2,"\n"}'' rect.txt' with lines
```

Comment: I'm going for the latter option and it works well. Is there the possibility to set the color from data as well? Ideally using palette?

Comment: Do you want to fill the box, or change the border color?

Comment: I want to fill the box.

Comment: I succeed to fill it with filled curves but then I cannot set the color with data, like for example palette. (If it is not filled I can easily set the line color from data using palette.)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far :-) . I did ask a separate question for the coloring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035979/gnuplot-filledcurves-with-color-from-data