# gnuplot: filledcurves with color from data

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to use filledcurves with palette.

My data looks like this:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0.5
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 0.6
```

My plotting commands:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600
set output "test.png"
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
plot '< awk ''{print $1,$2,$9,"\n",$3,$4,$9,"\n",$5,$6,$9,"\n",$7,$8,$9,"\n",$1,$2,$9,"\n"}'' rect.txt' \
using 1:2:3 with filledcurves fillcolor palette notitle
```

This unfortunately only yields black squares where as I would like them to be colored. Is there a way to achieve correctly colored figures with gnuplot?

**EDIT:**

Using as suggested:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600
set output "test.png"
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
file = 'rect.txt'
lines = system(sprintf('wc -l %s | cut -d'' '' -f 1', file))
frac(x) = system(sprintf('awk ''{if (NR==%d){ print $9 }}'' %s', x, file))
rect(x) = sprintf('awk ''{if (NR==%d){ print $1,$2,$4,"\n",$5,$8,$6,"\n"}}'' %s', x, file)
plot for [i=1:lines] '< '.rect(i) using 1:2:3 with filledcurves palette frac frac(i) notitle
```

with the content of rect.txt:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0.5
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 0.6
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 0.2
```

yields the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filledcurves` plotting style doesn't support coloring by palette with data from a file. The main issue here is, that usually, when using `palette`, one wants to change the color within a single area depending on some data values.

To color a single rectangle taking the color value from a fractional position of the palette, you can use `palette frac <value>`. This requires you to iterate over all rectangles.

And for proper use with `filledcurves`, you need a different data format, like

```
x1 y1_low y1_high
x2 x2_low y2_high
```

Since you are using `awk` anyways, you can extract some more information for the actual plotting:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600
set output "test.png"
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
file = 'rect.txt'
lines = system(sprintf('wc -l %s | cut -d'' '' -f 1', file))
frac(x) = system(sprintf('awk ''{if (NR==%d){ print $9 }}'' %s', x, file))
rect(x) = sprintf('awk ''{if (NR==%d){ print $1,$2,$4,"\n",$5,$8,$6,"\n"}}'' %s', x, file)
plot for [i=1:lines] '< '.rect(i) using 1:2:3 with filledcurves palette frac frac(i) notitle
```

With the data file

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0.5
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 0.6
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 0.2
```

you get the output

[image]

Comment: Using your code I only get 2 squares plotted... And if I change the last value of the lines to 10,5,0 then I get `line 11: palette fraction out of range`. And the I don not see yet how the colors of the squares correlates with the last value in the data...  Is it value times 10?

Comment: Are you sure you used my data file with the three lines? The keyword `frac` gives you a color for a certain fraction from the palette. The values must be in the range `[0:1]`. If you want to provide absolute values, just drop the `frac`. Possibly you need to fix the cbrange.

Comment: I have checked multiple times. I have edited my question to show you what result I get. Instead of three I only get two squares.

Comment: Hm, I can't really help you debugging, for me it works fine. Have you checked if the individual calls work fine? What does `print lines` (inside the gnuplot script/gnuplot terminal give you? If this is not `3`, what does `wc -l rect.txt` on the shell give? Does `print frac(1)`, `print frac(2)`, and `print frac(3)` return what you expect? etc.